# Can I charge a 4000 mAh Li-po battery with a single TP4056 module?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, charger, step-up, tp4056

I bought a single 4000 mAh lithium-polymer battery and connected a step up converter and TP4056 module.

I am providing a circuit image; the only difference between the image and the actual circuit is that I used a 4000 mAh battery.

[image]

But is it possible to charge a single 4000 mAh battery with a single TP4056 charging module, and is there any possible flaw in my circuit?

Comment: "kilomilli": made me chuckle! Don't write that. Either just write "4 Ah" or "4000 mAh"; writing "1000 of 1/0000" is confusing, and I had to first think about the distance, kilometer, which has the symbol "km".

Comment: Can you guarantee you will not be charging the battery and using the step-up converter at the same time?

Comment: The thing is in this step up converter that led is always on when the circuit is closed so the converter is always working led wise but i can assure you i won't plugin the converter and charge the module at the same time. Even now I've cut connections to the converter while charging the battery. But yeah i plugged in and charged at the same time for a minute or two.

Comment: Should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can charge it that way, but it will be slow.

There is a flaw: your load device should connect to the load terminals of the module, not to the battery wires.

Comment: Is there any way to increase it's charging speed?

Answer (score 0):

Note that your battery is not "well" connected!
There are two points named B+ and B-. You should connect your battery there ...
Only B+ is connected to "+" wire. Not B- to "-".
Unless the correct connections are done, protection circuitry does not properly  "function".

Note also that some "green" boards can perform both functions (charge and load functions).

from this https://buger.dread.cz/tag/module.html

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you kindly list a green pcb board that can do both?

Comment: Same as this which are found in these box power bank https://www.befr.ebay.be/itm/304370971695?hash=item46ddec742f:g:kpIAAOSwsW1fo2nd https://www.amazon.nl/AZDelivery-Module-Controller-connector-inclusief/dp/B07YWSMKVN/ref=asc_df_B07YWSMKVN/?tag=nlshogostdde-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=472122620630&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=11825285614154228277&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=1001344&hvtargid=pla-971020253981&th=1

Comment: Are they custom made or i can get them online ready made?

Comment: googling only     "2x 18650 usb power bank board" docs: https://wnsnty.xyz/entry/tp5400-datasheet-translated#pinfunction

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Also is there any way I can extend it's charging speed, it takes too much time to get charged and also charge.

Comment: There are "fast" chargers but they need "more" electronics ... as those which are used for charging the batteries of power tools (18 V). Don't know if some exist for a single 18650 battery voltage or similar.

Comment: For "fast" charging, I found this https://www.ebay.fr/itm/113932427202

Comment: Thank you again!